# Are self-cleaning sensors now standard?

Tags: dslr, sensor, cleaning

As someone who shoots out-of-doors a lot, I am very pleased to have a self-cleaning sensor. I don't see this feature mentioned much in camera reviews, and I am wondering whether they are now a standard feature on DSLRs.

Comment: Please note that while there is a dust removal system in these types of cameras, that does not mean you won;t even have to remove dust.  They're useful but not perfect.

Comment: @StephenG, I'm not sure I understand your comment. Are you saying that one should properly clean one's sensor even if it is self-cleaning?

Comment: No, I'm saying that "self cleaning" is just one level of protection from dust.  It's still possible to get dust (or more persist things like pollen) on your sensor assembly that won't necessarily be removed by self cleaning.  It's useful to do the standard check for dust if you have a chance.  This spots problems before they turn up in shots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Among digital cameras with interchangeable lenses, this is now an *almost* standard feature.

Let's look at DSLRs first, since you mention those explicitly. Among 105 DSLRs released since May 2005, only 7 do not have automatic sensor cleaning. Half of those are from 2010 and earlier with the latest two *not* having sensor cleaning being the Sigma SD1 Merrill from 2012 and Nikon D3400 that was released in 2016.

For mirrorless cameras, integrating cleaning is also now the norm. Among 123 mirrorless cameras launched since May 2005, only 10 do not have integrated sensor cleaning. Oddly, unlike with DSLRs, the number of mirrorless cameras without sensor cleaning has not been diminishing. In 2013, there were 2, 3 in 2014, 1 in 2015 and 4 (!!!) in 2016. That latest 2016 batch is the Sigma SD Quattro, the Sigma SD Quattro H, the Hasselblad X1D-50c and the Canon EOS M5.

*May 2005 is when I launched [Neocamera](https://www.neocamera.com/), so its database includes all cameras launched from then on by all major manufacturers. You can use the [Camera Search](https://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php) tool to find out which camera has built-in Dust-Reduction by selecting the corresponding icon.*

Comment: Your camera search tool is very handy, but it does have some errors. The Canon EOS M5 user guide says the camera does have built-in Dust-Reduction (automatic sensor cleaning). The following Canon EOS DSLRs do NOT have built-in Dust-Reduction. (automatic sensor cleaning) :  T3/1100D, T5/1200D, T6/1300D, T7/2000D, and T100/4000D.

Comment: @MikeSowsun - That you. Will have this corrected on the next DB update. We often get incomplete into at the time of launch which is when the info is added first.